# Закрытие консольного приложения (после отработки) внутри другого консольного

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

//первое консольное

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
        ps.FileName = @"C:\Users\user\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = ps;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();


        Console.WriteLine("next work is ...");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

//второе консольное приложение

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello world");

        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Yegor\Desktop");

        var files = di.GetFiles("*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (var f in files) {
            fun();
            Console.WriteLine($"{f.Name} is handled");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void fun() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int n = i;
        }
    }
```

Первое вызывает второе. При этом у второй программы есть некая работа, то есть оно сначала должно отработать, а затем быть закрытым. Закрывается по нажатию клавиши Enter. Необходимо программно закрыть это окно нажатием Enter или красным крестиком. ReadLine() убирать не нужно, так как доступа к коду в реальной программе у меня нет. Как же закрыть второе приложение после отработки? у меня получилось это сделать с помощью Thread.Sleep() с помощью p.Close() но закрытие происходит сразу, не дожидаясь окончания обработки неизвестного количества файлов. 
Пробовал

```
[DllImport("User32.Dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA")]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    const int VK_RETURN=0x0D;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern void ExitProcess([In] uint uExitCode);
```

а также

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

а также

```
p.Kill(); //Refresh(), Dispose()
```

все дело в WaitForExit() после которой ничего из этого не работает, а она нужна чтобы дождаться пока отработает обработка всех файлов. Как же дождаться отработки второго консольного приложения, а затем его закрыть программно?

Comment: можно попробовать ввести сроку во входной поток

Comment: это как, объясните пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) ожидает ввода строки на стандартный поток ввода.

Чтобы можно было ввести строку автоматически, нужно установить свойство [`RedirectStandardInput`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) в объекте класса [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) в значение `true`.

И просто записать строку в стандартный поток ввода, например так:

```
p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
```

---

В результате код первого консольного приложения может стать таким:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
    ps.FileName = @"C:\Users\user\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApp2.exe";
    ps.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = ps;
    p.Start();

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
    p.WaitForExit();


    Console.WriteLine("next work is ...");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```